# Is there any way to bring all work item types on VSTS task board?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

While configuring using the given settings option we are able to bring Bug & task only on task board but need features work item type to be available as well there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. The way VSTS/TFS is setup you can only bring one level to the boards at a time.

- At the task board level this is tasks/bugs in swimlanes of Story/PBI/Requirement/Bugs (special case).
- At the Product Backlog level this is the Story/PBI/Requirement
- At the Feature level these are features
- At the Epic level these are Epics.

As such an epic must be broken down into features first and then into PBI's and then into tasks to show up on the Task board.

The only exception here is the Bug workitem and this is more of a historical oddity because in the original Scrum template bugs lived at the Product backlog level while they lived at a Task level in the Agile template before the advent of boards altogether. It's also why the Bug work item has such a strange mix of fields.

One way to easily drive the breakdown is to change the type of a work item, so you can change an Epic to a PBI/Userstory and thus have it move 2 levels down. But then it won't show up at the Epic level anymore.

Comment: You're welcome. Some of the features in the product have a very long history and can make certain things confusing. I tend to lock Bug on the Product Backlog, like Scrum intends it to be and remove the extra fields in a custom inherited process template.